# Castle Windsor: inject IEnumerable<IService> using only a subset of registered components for IService

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Consider the following scenario of services and components in a sample C# console application

```
public interface IService { }
public class FooService: IService { }
public class BarService: IService { }
public class BuzzService: IService { }
public class AwesomeService: IService { }

public class Consumer 
{
    public Consumer(IEnumerable<IService> services)
    {
        // do some initilization work here...
    }
}

public class AnotherConsumer 
{
    public AnotherConsumer(IEnumerable<IService> services)
    {
        // do some initilization work here...
    }
}
```

Let's imagine to do the following registrations inside the composition root:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel, true));

container.Register(Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<FooService>());
container.Register(Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<BarService>());
container.Register(Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<BuzzService>());
container.Register(Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<AwesomeService>());

container.Register(Component.For<Consumer>());
container.Register(Component.For<AnotherConsumer>());

// consumer got injected all 4 different implementations of IService
// due to CollectionResolver
var consumer = container.Resolve<Consumer>();

// anotherConsumer got injected all 4 different implementations of 
// IService due to CollectionResolver
var anotherConsumer = container.Resolve<AnotherConsumer>();
```

This kind of scenario works fine and I did so several times.

What if, for some reason, I would like to inject **inside the constructor of Consumer class** only **two different implementations of IService**, for instance only FooService and BarService (**while still continuing to inject all the available implementations of IService inside the constructor of AnotherConsumer**) ?

Is there an elegant way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I grabbed my copy of [the first edition](https://manning.com/seemann) of [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl). It contains a complete chapter on Castle Windsor and discusses this exact scenario. The trick is to do two things:

- Define the collection registrations as named registrations using `.Named(string)`
- Specify an override for `Consumer` using `.ServiceOverrides(object)`

The following code sample is almost straight out of the book (with the names replaced with your examples):

```
container.Register(Component
    .For<IService>()
    .ImplementedBy<FooService>()
    .Named("Foo"));
container.Register(Component
    .For<IService>()
    .ImplementedBy<BarService>()
    .Named("Bar"));
container.Register(Component
    .For<IService>()
    .ImplementedBy<BuzzService>()
    .Named("Buzz"));
container.Register(Component
    .For<IService>()
    .ImplementedBy<AwesomeService>()
    .Named("Awesome"));

container.Register(Component
    .For<Consumer>()
    .ServiceOverrides(new
        {
            services = new[] { "Foo", "Bar" }
        }));

container.Register(Component.For<AnotherConsumer>());

var consumer = container.Resolve<Consumer>();
```

Comment: Hi @Steven we finally implemented the same solution and we took inspiration from the same book (thanks to Mark Seeman for his awesome book). Just as a sidenote, the castle windsor api has changed slightly in the latest version: you can find the details [here](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/inline-dependencies.md).

Comment: What we don't like about this approach is that it is not refactoring friendly and it could potentially create an unwanted dependency. The registration of class Consumer depends on the identifier "services" which is the name of the constructor parameter, that means you can break the registration by means of a rename refactoring over the constructor parameter (I don't know how to leverage the nameof() operator for this scenario).

Comment: This could be acceptable if the class Consumer was defined in the same assembly, or at least in the same solution, of the composition root. What if you get the Consumer class from a third party package ? In that case,  your registration depends on something you cannot control because the library author could freely change the parameter name during a refactoring session.

Comment: You can't leverage `nameof` in this scenario. But do note that a changing a parameter name of a public member **is** a breaking change. This is breaking, because both C# and VB allow a developer to used named parameters. A library developer, therefore, should be aware of such change to be breaking.

Comment: But I do agree, I don't like the approach either. Perhaps you would have more luck while using a different DI Container, if that's an option.

Comment: Good catch about the parameter name breaking change: I didn't carefully thought about that (actually i don't use named params very often). I just noticed that you are the author of Simple Injector and the co-author of the second edition of Dependency injection in .NET. Thanks for your effort as an editor and as a developer: both products are great.

Answer (score 3):

The answer that @Steven gave is very much on point. There's a slightly nicer API to do that (added in version 3 of Windsor, so not covered by the aforementioned book) without having to use `.Named` or registering all your `IService`s one by one.

```
container.Register(Component
    .For<Consumer>()
    .DependsOn(
       Dependency.OnComponentCollection(
          "services", typeof(FooService), typeof(BarService)
       )
    )
);
```

Or if you don't want to use the dependency name, you can specify it by type

```
container.Register(Component
    .For<Consumer>()
    .DependsOn(
       Dependency.OnComponentCollection<IEnumerable<IService>>(
          typeof(FooService), typeof(BarService)
       )
    )
);
```

With that you can just register your `IComponent`s via convention like the following, without any extra fuss.

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
    .BasedOn<IService>()
    .WithServiceBase()
    .LifestyleTransient());
```

Comment: this way we can avoid depending on parameter name, this is cool. We will probably opt for this solution.

Comment: I updated the answer to use the generic version of the by-type scenario which is slightly more readable